# Object to JSON in nested collection with Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, collections

I'm new to the Spring Framework and trying to build RESTful web service. Now I'm a bit stuck with this problem.

I have some entity classes like UserDetails (getters/setters, equals() and hashCode() omitted):

```
public class UserDetails {

    private Long userId;
    private String login;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    private Map<ActionDetails, Boolean> confirmedActionsMap;
}
```

and ActionDetails (again getters/setters, equals() and hashCode() omitted):

```
public class ActionDetails {

    private Long actionId;
    private String actionName;
    private String actionDescription;
}
```

I have a method in my @RestController returning UserDetails:

```
@GET
@RequestMapping("/user")
@Produces ({ "application/json" })
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(){

    UserDetails userDetails = //obtaining user somehow

    return new ResponseEntity<User>(userDetails, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

But in response I get JSON with ActionDetails in map not serialized to JSON, but simply called toString() on it:

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "login": "j.doe",
    "firstname": "John",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "confirmedActionsMap": {"com.example.ActionDetails@d4955b30": true}
}
```

ActionDetails themselves beeing returned by other controller methods are serialized to JSON just fine.
What is the most appropriate approach to serialize objects in collections in REST with Spring?

Comment: it calls ActionDetails.toString() because it is the key of the map in this case.

Comment: i propose to create two types of list confirmedActionsList and NotConfirmedActionsList and Omit the boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Map` is a representation of `key`, `value` pairs. Calling `toString()` on the key is the only logical way of representing the key.

If you want to serialize the `ActionDetail` differently, I'd suggest wrapping `ActionDetail`, `Boolean` in another class and putting that in a `List`.

For example:

```
public class UserDetails {
    private Long userId;
    private String login;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<ActionDetailWrapper> confirmedActions;
}

public class ActionDetails {
    private Long actionId;
    private String actionName;
    private String actionDescription;
}

public class ActionDetailWrapper {
    private ActionDetails actionDetails;
    private Boolean result;
}
```

Alternatively you could key your `Map` using the `actionId` from `ActionDetails` and add the `Boolean` into the `ActionDetails` class.